# Using AngularJs Promise to Retrieve and Store an Entity

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Following submission of a form to an AngularJS controller method, I need to take the value of a select menu (which in this case is the entity id) and retrieve that entity from my REST endpoint. I understand that when I use $http.get, the data is being retrieve asynchronously and so storing this data can be tricky.

I have been trying to follow a few articles which cover promises and deferring but I haven't quite gotten it right yet.

In the following example, **I want to come away with a Room object**. Right now, I'm just getting an empty object as seen here:

```
{"room":{},"user":{"userId":1,"userName":"tom","links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost:8080/libroomreserve/api/user/1"}]},"startTime":"2011-01-10 00:00:00","endTime":"2011-01-10 00:00:00","note":"weewwe"}
```

This is my controller method:

```
$scope.newReservation = function(){
        var packagedUser = reservationService.fetchRoomObj($scope.reservation.room).then(function(roomObj){
            return roomObj;
        });
        var finalReservation = {
            room: packagedUser,
            user: $scope.reservation.user,
            startTime: $scope.reservation.startTime,
            endTime: $scope.reservation.endTime,
            note: $scope.reservation.note
        };
        reservationService.addReservation(
            finalReservation,
            function(data){
                console.log("Success!");
                $state.go("home");
            },
            function(data){
                console.log("Failure!");
            }
        );
    };
```

As you can see, I am trying to use the promise from my factory service's method (below) to retrieve the object.

```
reservations.fetchRoomObj = function(room){
    return $http.get("/libroomreserve/api/room/" + room).then(function(response){
            console.log("success http!");
            console.log(response);
            return response;
    });
};
```

My console.log() calls return the object just fine so I know my only error is in properly storing my response data to a variable.

Here's the actual HTML form if that helps...

```
    <form ng-submit="newReservation()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Start </label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.startTime" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>End </label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.endTime" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <!--<div class="form-group">
            <label>User </label>
            <input type="number" ng-model="reservation.user" class="form-control">
        </div>-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Room </label>
            <select ng-model="reservation.room" class="form-control">
                <option ng-repeat="room in roomsList" value="{{ room.roomId }}">{{ room.roomNumber }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Note</label>
            <textarea ng-model="reservation.note" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Reserve</button>
    </form>
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cpuzzuol/jorwgkr6/3/)

Comment: If i understood well, you get something in your console.log(response) but dont know how to stock it ?

Comment: Well, the manner you call reservationService.fetchRoomObj() doesn't will return immediately the room... If you put your code on jsbin or jsfiddle, we can help you to adjust your code...

Comment: @ThomasP1988 correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to continue your code only after the call of then() method:

```
$scope.newReservation = function() {
    reservationService.fetchRoomObj($scope.reservation.room).then(function(roomObj) {
        var finalReservation = {
            room: roomObj,
            user: $scope.reservation.user,
            startTime: $scope.reservation.startTime,
            endTime: $scope.reservation.endTime,
            note: $scope.reservation.note
        };
        reservationService.addReservation(
            finalReservation,
            function(data){
                console.log("Success!");
                $state.go("home");
            },
            function(data){
                console.log("Failure!");
            }
        );
    });
};
```

I used the roomObj directly to make the finalReservation object, and then, I call the addReservation() function.

Comment: Here's a good explanation of what's going on here for anybody else in the future:

http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: If you need to read more than one promise before your function, the $q.all() will help too

Comment: That $q.all() tip saved me hours of aimless research as I would have had no idea where to start looking. I do need to run both a Room and User entity lookup at the same time for my next step. Now that I understand how the basic promise works, using $q is pretty straightforward. HUGE help! Thank you.

Link to $q.all() mini tutorial: http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

Answer (score 0):

The $http legacy promise method "success" have been deprecated. Use the standard "then" method instead.

```
 return $http.get("/libroomreserve/api/room/" + room).then(function(response){
        console.log("success http!");
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
});
```

Comment: Good to know. However, that has not fixed the problem.